# Replace Xml attribute value with filename for all Xml-Files in directory and all subdirectories

Tags: xml, sed, grep, find

got a question for all of you sed | find | xmllint | xargs experts out there:

I need a script to replace the value of Xml-attribute someXmlTag
for all *.xml files in a directory (and subdirectories) with the current
filename (without extension)

Bonues assignment:
I need a script to replace the value of Xml-Tag  with the first part of the filename (before a delimiter) and Xml-Tag  with the second part of the filename (after a delimiter) for all *.xml files in a directory (and subdirectories)

Thanks in advance, your help is appreciated!

regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any examples, test-cases.
Anyway this find/xargs/sed will find all files with `.xml` suffix in current directory and replace inside `<xmlTag>` or `</xmlTag>` to `<newTag>` or `</newTag>`:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\(<\/\{,1\}\)xmlTag/\1newTag/g'
```

Test:

```
$ cat file.xml
<xmlTag>
</xmlTag>
<xmlTag>Whats up</xmlTag>

$ sed 's/\(<\/\{,1\}\)xmlTag/\1newTag/g' file.xml
<newTag>
</newTag>
<newTag>Whats up</newTag>
```